# Как вывести в уведомлении ссылку на БП?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Есть БП в CRM. Руководителю необходимо утвердить счет. При запуске БП руководителю приходит уведомление что Вам необходимо утвердить счет и нужно чтобы в этом уведомлении была ссылка на утверждение документа. Как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Речь, как я понял, идёт об уведомлении "в колокольчик". Тогда:

1. использовать в конструкторе БП следующее действие
   [image: Уведомление пользователю]

2. В нём прописать с помощью bb-кодов:
   [url=/company/personal/bizproc/**ID задания БП, которое руководителю нужно согласовать**/]Согласовать[/url]